# preg_replace not removed "class"

Tags: posts, images, post-thumbnails, hooks

Use this code to remove the label "class" of the images, but does not work. The label does not disappear in the new post.

```
function the_post_thumbnail_remove_class($output) {
        $output = preg_replace('/class=".*?"/', '', $output);
        return $output;
}
add_filter('post_thumbnail_html', 'the_post_thumbnail_remove_class');
```

It only works on the main page with highlighted images(thumbnail).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hook [`post_thumbnail_html`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-includes/post-thumbnail-template.php#L141) is just working for featured images aka post thumbnails, hence the name. I'm guessing that's what you're missing and where the "problem" originates.

But luckily there is another hook for manipulating image tags [`get_image_tag`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-includes/media.php#L240), there is actually one for just altering the class [`get_image_tag_class`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-includes/media.php#L236) too. Take a look into those.

Another hook used in these scenarios is [`wp_get_attachment_image_attributes`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-includes/media.php#L567), but I only mention this one for completeness reasons.